# Material design Lite - Navigation lock in place

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design-lite

```
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">SITE NAME</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Hi i am trying to figure out how I get this menu to ALWAYS (unless mobile) lock inside the users view, and for the site grid to resize. but one step at a time how do I get this to lock (so users can't close or open)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code.  Dictation of fixed drawer should be in a div class above the drawer. It was taken from the MDL page, https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout
and look under fixed header, there is also a code pen available.

```html
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer">
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content">
      <!-- Your content goes here -->
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```